# How to get the headings to work separately in this codepen

Tags: jquery

the codepen I am looking at is this. http://codepen.io/candygong/pen/OMZqNZ

I was wondering how to get the headings to work separate from each other (for example when you click one the other one does not slide down.) I know I could assign separate classes for each one but I was wondering how to do it more efficiently as I was planning on trying to use many different headers so I would like to use the same class instead of creating a class for each instance.

HTML code

```
<section>
<h1 class="question">q: what is this: hahahahplop?</h1>
<p class="answer"><span>a: someone laughing their head off!</span></p>
</section>

<section>
<h1 class="question">q: what is this: hahahahplop?</h1>
<p class="answer"><span>a: someone laughing their head off!</span></p>
</section>
```

CSS code

```
* {
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}

body {
font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
font-size: 20px;
color: #555;
}

section {
width: 5in;
margin: 24px auto;
text-align: center;
}

section h1.question {
color: white;
background-color: purple;
padding: 24px;
font-weight: 500;
border-top-left-radius: 10px;
border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}

section p.answer {
border: 1px gray solid;
border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
padding:36px 0px;
}
```

Javascript code

```
$(function() {
console.log("ready");

$('section p.answer').hide();
$('section p.answer span').hide();

$('section h1.question').click(function(){

$('section p.answer').slideToggle();
$('section p.answer span').fadeToggle();
})
});
```

I know you should be able to use the this keyword but I have been unable to get it to work myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because there are two different "section p.answer" objects you need to get the right one on click:

```js
$(function() {
  //hide the answer
  $('section p.answer').hide();
  $('section p.answer span').hide();
  //listen for a click on the question: same event attached to more objects
  $('section h1.question').click(function(e){
    // get the only one parent on which you clicked
    var sectionObj = $(this).parent('section');
    
    // act only on the corresponding children
    sectionObj.find('p.answer').slideToggle();
    sectionObj.find('p.answer span').fadeToggle();
  })
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #555;
}

section {
  width: 5in;
  margin: 24px auto;
  text-align: center;
}

section h1.question {
  color: white;
  background-color: purple;
  padding: 24px;
  font-weight: 500;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}

section p.answer {
  border: 1px gray solid;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  padding:36px 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

<section>
    <h1 class="question">q: what is this: hahahahplop?</h1>

    <p class="answer"><span>a: someone laughing their head off!</span></p>
</section>

<section>
    <h1 class="question">q: what is this: hahahahplop?</h1>

    <p class="answer"><span>a: someone laughing their head off!</span></p>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in selecting elements you are going to show/hide: you selecting not desired elements, to fix problem access them via [this](https://coding.abel.nu/2013/04/this-and-this-in-jquery-callbacks/) and use [siblings method](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) within click handler, so basically you have to **replace lines in click handler from**:

```
$('section p.answer').slideToggle();
$('section p.answer span').fadeToggle();
```

**to**

```
$(this).siblings('p.answer').slideToggle();
$(this).siblings('p.answer span').fadeToggle();
```

See working code snippet on [**code pen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XdmQME)